# Transform Variable

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame as shown below:

```
 Country Year   X1  X2  convex1 convex2
   UK   2011    100 5   
   UK   2012    110 5.5
   UK   2013    NA  10  
   UK   2014    115 2
   US   2011    NA  10
   US   2012    120 11
   US   2013    118 9.2
   US   2014    NA  NA
```

And I would like to create two new variables to capture convexity. These two variables will apply the following logic:

**Convex1 if X1>average (X1 by country) then 1 else 0**

I have pinned down Convex1 using

```
  dataa <- data.table(dataa , key = "Country")
  dataa[ , convex1 := (X1 ) /mean(X1, na.rm = TRUE), "Country" ]
  dataa$convex1var<- ifelse(dataa$convex1>1.1 ,1 ,0)
```

But I would like to do it in one step as I have to perform this for a long list of vars.

**Convex2 if X2>= 10 for two consecutive years (by country) then 1 else 0**

For Convex2, I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: "*But I would like to do it in one step*"... write a function that does your steps. Now you can do it in one step: your function!

Comment: For convex2, check out `?diff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     dataa$Convex2<-ifelse( dataa$X2 > lag(dataa$X2, by=Country) &             
           lag(dataa$X2, by=Country) > lag(dataa$X2,2, by=Country),1,0)
```